# Entity Framework mapping tables with many attributes

Tags: entity-framework

I have a table with over two hundred columns. 
Sometimes I have to work with the hole amount of columns, sometimes I have cases that I only need some columns. Not only selecting that subsets is important, also update of values.

So my question: Can I map two different POCOs to same table?
Poco1 (with Column1 to Column10)
Poco2 (with Column1 to Column250)

Is this a supported mapping?
I know about table splitting and complex types. But I also need the poco with all attributes.

I use code first but on an existing database.

BR

Comment: Create another context with a mapping to the full POCO.

Comment: Maybe I could use inheritance per table mapping. But I have no diskriminator column for this. The user desides what set of columns should be used.